# logica de loop em blocos em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, lógica

Meu código tem um array com inúmeros objetos, esse abjetos os quais são URL'S, com eles faço um loop que percorre todo este array e faz um request para cada url do array. **Mas preciso que meu loop percorra o array em blocos, **Ex: de 10 em 10;** até chegar no final**, tudo isso para que não o faça instantaneamente e acabe sobrecarregando o servidor e também  para que não demore muito percorrendo de 1 em 1 pois o array é muito grande, á **base do código é basicamente isso.**

```
const array = ["URL-1","URL-2","URL-3"] etc...

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    axios.get(array[i], (res) => {
        const res = res;
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

bom no final eu mesmo acabei achando um jeito viável.

```
const main = async () => 
{
    if ( array.length >= index ) 
    {   
        if (index != count) 
        {
            console.log(index); 
            index++ 
            main();             
        }else{
            console.log("+10");
            count = (count + 10);
        }
        
    }else{
        console.log("end");
        clearInterval(handle);
    }
}
const handle = setInterval(main, 2000);
```

Obrigado por nada.

Comment: "Obrigado por nada" é ofensivo. Ninguém é obrigado a te ajudar. Muito menos na hora que você espera. Se acha que este site é para isto, está no lugar errado.